# Rails: dynamically assigning field type from a Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, web, hash

I am trying to use a hash to display a form :

```
PREFIX_STR = "Prefix"
FIRST_STR = "First Name"

NEW_USER_HASH = Hash.new
NEW_USER_HASH[ "prefix" ] = { "label" => PREFIX_STR, "type" => "text_field" }
NEW_USER_HASH[ "first" ] = { "label" => FIRST_STR, "type" => "text_field" }
```

And in the new.html.erb, I have:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <% NEW_USER_HASH.each do |column_name,field_info|  %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label field_info["label"] %>
      <%= f.text_field column_name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

This works fine, but instead of f.text_field, I want that to be what's in field_info["type"]. Nothing I tried worked. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try `f.send(field_into["type"], column_name)`.

(Edited to remove "`to_sym`", which a commenter tells me is unnecessary (I thought `send` required symbols.)

Why this works:  `some_object.send("hello")` is simply another way of writing `some_object.hello`. In Ruby, invoking a "method" on an object is actually a form of message passing -- you're sending a message to that object, and the object interprets it as a method invocation (or doesn't -- with ruby metaprogramming something that looks like a method call need not be).

In this case, you have an object `f` which represents a `form_helper` object, so when you call `f.text_field`, you're sending a message to that object.  By using `f.send`, you do the same thing, except you can generate the content of that message dynamically.

Comment: This seems to work (I see the form, but still need to test it). I don't understand why it works yet, but I have something to start from.

Comment: Edited to remove the to_sym, and to add explanation of why it works.